# Postgres timescale hypertable: is separate index necessary?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timescaledb

I want to create a hypertable in  postgres timescale.

What I do is CREATE TABLE then CREATE INDEX and finally SELECT CREATE_HYPERTABLE.

My question: is CREATE INDEX necessary, helpful or problematic for a high performance of the hypertable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In short**: no indexes are needed to be created as TimescaleDB will create an index on time dimension by default. Depending on your usage you might want to create indexes to speedup select queries and it is good to create them after creating the hypertable.

**In more details:**

Creating hypertable with [`create_hypertable` function](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#create_hypertable) replaces the original PotgreSQL table with new table. Thus it is better to create hypertable and then create index. It also works to create index first, and then call `create_hypertable`. In such case the existing indexes will be recreated on the hypertable. It is important to remember that unique indexes and primary keys need to include time dimension column. And note that `create_hypertable` will create an index on the time dimension column by default.

In general, the considerations for creating indexes are the similar as with PostgreSQL: there are tradeoffs in using indexes. Indexes introduces overheads during data ingesting, while can improve select queries significantly. I suggest to check [the best practice of using indexes in TimescaleDB](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/schema-management#indexing-best-practices) and [the blog about using composite indexes for time-series queries](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/use-composite-indexes-to-speed-up-time-series-queries-sql-8ca2df6b3aaa/)

Comment: So for me the insert is slightly more critical than the select. Can I drop the index on a hypertable without problems?

Comment: Do you mean the default index on time? I think you can drop it or create hypertable without it.

Comment: Just set this argument `create_default_indexes` to FALSE as  per documentation `Boolean whether to create default indexes on time/partitioning columns. Default is TRUE.`